# Query Author Apex Permission?

Tags: apex, soql, query, permissions, user

I'm trying to figure out how to query all users who have `Author Apex` permission (or any other system permissions). I thought it would be straightforward, but I don't see where it would be stored. With [`ObjectPermissions`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_objectpermissions.htm) I can see which objects can be accessed, and with [`SetupEntityAccess`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_setupentityaccess.htm) I can see which setup entities can be accessed. Looking at the `SetupEntityType` picklist, the available types of setup entity are:

- ApexClass
- ApexPage
- ConnectedApplication
- ConnectedApplication
- CustomPermission
- ExternalDataSource
- ExternalSocialAccount
- NamedCredential
- TabSet

None of these types seem to help either. Maybe I'm just forgetting something obvious, but I can't think of how I would query for system permissions. Can it be done? Using which object?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just realized that my search for `Author Apex` on the [`PermissionSet`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_permissionset.htm) fields missed one that is meant as a catch-all:

> **Field Name**
> Permissions*PermissionName*
>
> **Type**
> `boolean`
>
> **Properties**
> Create, Filter, Update
>
> **Description**
> One field for each permission. If true, users assigned to this permission set have the named permission. The number of fields varies depending on the permissions for the organization and license type.

I debugged all the fields on `PermissionSet` and lo and behold, there is a field called `PermissionsAuthorApex`.

```
for (SObjectField field : SObjectType.PermissionSet.fields.getMap().values())
    if (String.valueOf(field).contains('Apex'))
        system.debug(field);
```

For completeness, you would run the following script to get this information (need more than one query):

```
Set<Id> permissionSetIds = new Map<Id, PermissionSet>([
    SELECT Id FROM PermissionSet WHERE PermissionsAuthorApex = true
]).keySet();
for (User user : [
    SELECT Name FROM User WHERE Id IN (
        SELECT AssigneeId FROM PermissionSetAssignment
        WHERE PermissionSetId IN :permissionSetIds
    )
]) system.debug(user);
```