# Query on UserRecordAccess shows all permission on apex class even when the user does not have author apex permission

Tags: soql, soap-api

I am having an SOQL query just to check that which user is having what all permissions to an apex class. So the SOQL looks like this

```
SELECT RecordId, HasReadAccess, HasAllAccess,HasDeleteAccess,HasEditAccess, HasTransferAccess, MaxAccessLevel
 FROM UserRecordAccess where UserId='0052v00000cDteP' and recordId='01p2v00000HaUmj'
```

here recordId is Id of ApexClass and userId is the id of the user which is assigned to custom System admin profile with author apex permission unchecked.

As per my understanding it should show me no edit access on the class, but it shows following result

[image]

why the result shows hasEditAccess as true when the user does not have author apex permission itself, also the user doesn't have any extra permission set assigned

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that your custom profile does not actually remove access to modify Apex code. If run against a Standard Platform User, this query returns the expected values (`HasReadAccess` true, `HasEditAccess` et al. false) in my org.

Since authoring Apex isn't permissioned on a per-class basis, the permission fields on `UserRecordAccess` aren't meaningful for Apex classes in quite the same way they are for sObjects. Classes don't have record-level sharing at all, for example.  If you just want to find out whether a user has Author Apex permission, query for that permission specifically. It's called `PermissionsAuthorApex`. [Here's an example](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/145427/query-author-apex-permission/145429) by Adrian Larson of how to perform that kind of query.